# Enhanced domains Salesforce will rollout enhanced domains on all orgs in 2023

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

Enhanced domains. Salesforce will rollout enhanced domains on all orgs in 2023 right. my sandbox is detecting the target org as "System is down!". How to solve this issues i need some articles for this issue.

Enhanced domains. Salesforce will rollout enhanced domains on all orgs in 2023 right. my sandbox is detecting the target org as "System is down!". How to solve this issues i need some articles for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question. Does the target org already has enhanced domains enabled? You can log in and check the release updates.

Are you doing some integration? Lightning Connect, REST API maybe? If you do - did you mess the initial login call up? If you hardcoded sandbox's name as `mydomainname--mysandbox.my.salesforce.com` then it's your fault. Yes, the integration will fail to find it after enhanced domains are on. You should never hardcode like that. You're supposed to send login calls to generic login.salesforce.com / test.salesforce.com and READ THE FINAL URL from login response (you already read access_token but probably ignore the instance_url which will be valid, whether enhanced domains are on or not).